# Notepad++ v6.7.8.2 unwanted tabs after pressing enter

Tags: notepad++

I mainly use NPP for writing PLSQL code. The standard I follow is 3 line spacing. I have observed that when I press enter after a line, the cursor goes correctly at the point exactly below where the previous line started. This is really good. But what it does is instead of putting spaces, it puts tabs for the empty spaces which has to be accommodated.

Example is below. Look at line 3, its has 2 tabs before the start of code, I expect 6 spaces instead of 2 tabs.

```
update cai_vsc_ordhead cvo
  set vsc_po_process_ind = 'Y',
      vsc_partial_recvd_ind = 'N'
where cvo.status   = 'C'
  and cvo.close_date >= L_start_date
  and cvo.close_date <= L_end_date
  and cvo.vsc_shipment_count = 1;
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to avoid tabs when we press enter?

Pic

Regards and Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of behavior]

Comment: Settings -> Options -> Tabs -> Replace with spaces (possible only for that language).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings->Preferences

Select Tab Settings from the left hand list (ensuring that [default] is selected on the right hand list, unless you want your changes to be language specific), and tick on the little tick box that says "Replace by space".

You can also set the number of spaces to insert by clicking on the blue number next to "Tab Size:" and updating it, for larger/smaller default tab indenting.

Comment: Awesome answer!! Thank You So Much Tim Radcliffe. You saved me from re-working and embarrassment from reviewers of my code.

Comment: Am wondering if this answer is still as per current version of software ? i.e. I don't see a "Tab Settings" option in left hand list ..

Answer (score 0):

As at Notepad++ v7.8.4:

'Settings' > 'Preferences...' > 'Language' (left pane)

'Tab Settings' is then on the right-hand side.